# angular-ui-router always appends app to url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The ui-router in our angular application always appends "#app" to the URLs in our app, which clearly is not desired behaviour. This also has the side-effect, that when you use the browser navigation (back and forward), you'll need two clicks to actually switch the page.

AngularJS version: 1.2.29

ui-router version: 0.2.10

The browser history looks like so:

http://localhost:8080/app/#/modulename

http://localhost:8080/app/#/modulename#app <- unnecessary step

http://localhost:8080/app/#/anothermodule

http://localhost:8080/app/#/anothermodule#app <-unnecessary step

... and so on.

We already tried switching to ui-router's html5mode, but this just omits the first hash-sign in the URL and doesn't have any effect on anything else.

This is our stateProvider

```
$stateProvider
                .state('app', {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: '/',
                    // parent: true,
                    templateUrl: CONFIG.baseUrl + '/js/modules/Core/View/app.html',
                })
                .state('access.404', {
                    url: '/404',
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/page_404.html'
                });
```

Comment: check your base or  set base to `/`  using   just `ng build --prod --base / ` (angular 2+) . i believe you are using AngularJs (1.x)  not Angular (2+ ) then you should   set base in index.html  `<base href="/">`

Comment: Also  this article may help you : http://joeljoseph.net/angularjs-remove-hash-from-url/

Comment: Sorry, that should be AngularJS of course, with the version I stated.

Comment: Kindly refer https://ui-router.github.io/about/, I think you need this type URL which is visible in image of links. Please wait a moment, I will post answer here. Thanks.

Comment: @AkashPatel As you can see in the excerpt of the browser history I posted, we're using the kind of URL scheme shown on the site already.